# Selenium is not running with Firefox 12.0

Tags: selenium, testng

Selenium is not working after Firefox upgraded to latest version 12.0. It is failing with below message. Please advise, it is still working fine if i use older version of firefox.

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\Abdul\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous869859993705622974webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:78)
    at Google.Open_Google_Firefox.Test_Google_FireFox(Open_Google_Firefox.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:702)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:894)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1219)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:768)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1022)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:109)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:202)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:173)
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod tearDown
```

..
..
..
..

Comment: What version of selenium are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same error with 2.16.  Upgrading to 2.21.2 allowed me to use Firefox 12.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling the current version and re-installing the previous version of Firefox solves this issue.

This is because, the latest version of Firefox is not integrated with the current Selenium version.

Answer (score 0):

And if you revert back to Firefox 11? (or lower?)

If you revert back and it is still an issue, have a look on Selenium's website and report it as a bug. If it is indeed a bug, I would not be too surprised if other's have also reported it.